# ggplot - Bar Plots lacking filling the bar correctly when being saved

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill

I'm trying to save some of my plots and for some reason, the plots are not coming well-filled. I've already updated my packages, and my R is also updated. I tried to restart the PC and many other things and I can't understand why this is happening. For now It's only with bar plots.

Reproducible Example:

```
     p <-- tibble(month = sample(1:12, size = 1000, replace = T), 
     cases = sample(1:1000)) %>% ggplot(aes(as.factor(month), cases))+
geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
xlab ("Mês")+
ylab('Casos')+
ggtitle('B')
ggsave(p, "fig1.png")
```

My results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens (maybe something to do with antialiasing?) but you can prevent it by setting the `fill` and the border colour `col` for your bars to be the same.

Eg:

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(month = sample(1:12, size = 1000, replace = T), 
       cases = sample(1:1000)) %>% ggplot(aes(as.factor(month), cases))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="grey40", col="grey40")+
  xlab ("Mês")+
  ylab('Casos')+
  ggtitle('B')

ggsave("test.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried this but had no results, unfortunately, I believe it's a problem with ggsave(), cause on another computer the same problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I had to change the way to save, using:

```
jpeg("fig01.jpeg", width = 24, height = 15,units="in",res=144)
p
dev.off()
```